# Get object properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I try to get my object properties with:

```
PropertyInfo[] p = typeof(Myobj).GetProperties()
```

but I receive only

```
{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]}
```

My object looks like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class Myobj
{
  public Subobj1 sub1= new Subobj1();
  public Subobj2 sub2= new Subobj2();
  //...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They are *fields* not properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c

Comment: Use `typeof(Myobj).GetFields()` instead

Comment: Hehe, too much coffee, you are all right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating real properties. You are creating fields instead.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class Myobj
{
    public Subobj1 Sub1 {get; set;}
    public Subobj2 Sub2 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `sub1` and `sub2` are not properties, they're fields. Change your class declaration to something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    class Myobj
    {
        public Subobj1 sub1 {get; set; }
        public Subobj2 sub2 {get; set; }

...
    }
```

And initialize the properties with new objects inside your constructor.

Optionally, you can try using the [`GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx) method instead, but that's not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

`sub1` and `sub2` are fields not properties. Try declare

```
public Subobj1 sub1 { get; set; }
public Subobj2 sub2 { get; set; }

public Myobj()
{
    sub1 = new Subobj1();
    sub2 = new Subobj2();
}
```

If you don't want to change the fields to properties you can use `typeof(Myobj).GetFields();`

Answer (score 0):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    class Myobj
    {
        public Myobj() {
             sub1 = new Subobj1();
             sub2 = new Subobj2();
        }

        public Subobj1 sub1 { get; set; }
        public Subobj2 sub2 { get; set; }
    }
```